# How to add +1 to a variable for every X minutes past in the timer in the code

Tags: time, while-loop, count, counter

I have 3 variables (ADG,DR,TC) that I want to count for every single time 45 mins and 2.5 hrs pass, respectively for each 3 variable. I have this code to create a 24 hrs timer and I need to add these variables (and their counts) into while when_to_stop > 0: loop. Any recommendations? Thank you!

```
import time

while True:
    uin = input(">>")
    try:
        when_to_stop = abs(int(uin))
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        break
    except:
        print("Not a number!")

    while when_to_stop > 0:
        m, s = divmod(when_to_stop, 60)
        h, m = divmod(m, 60)
        time_left = str(h).zfill(2) + ":" + str(m).zfill(2) + ":" + str(s).zfill(2)
        print(time_left + "\r", end="" )
        time.sleep(0.001)
        when_to_stop -= 1

        # ADG - Auto Droplet Generator (45 mins)
        # DR - Droplet Reader (time same as TC)
        # TC - Ther mal cycler  (2.5 hrs)

"""
```

Answer (score 0):

Added an elapsed seconds counter.

When the amount of elapsed seconds is evenly divisible by (45 * 60 seconds), 45 minutes have passed, and the ADG variable is incremented by one each time this happens.

When the amount of elapsed seconds is evenly divisible by (150 * 60 seconds), 2.5 hours have passed, and the TC variable is incremented by one each time this happens. The DR variable acts the same way (*time same as TC*) so it has the same value as the TC variable.

```
import time
elapsed = 0 
ADG = 0
DR = 0
TC = 0

while True:
    uin = input(">>")
    try:
        when_to_stop = abs(int(uin))
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        break
    except:
        print("Not a number!")

    while when_to_stop > 0:
        m, s = divmod(when_to_stop, 60)
        h, m = divmod(m, 60)
        time_left = str(h).zfill(2) + ":" + str(m).zfill(2) + ":" + str(s).zfill(2)
        print(time_left + "\r", end="" )
        time.sleep(0.001)
        when_to_stop -= 1
        elapsed += 1

        #Auto Droplet Generator (45 mins)
        if (elapsed % (45*60) == 0):
            ADG += 1 
        # DR - Droplet Reader (time same as TC)
        if (elapsed % (150*60) == 0):
            DR += 1        
        # TC - Ther mal cycler  (2.5 hrs)
        if (elapsed % (150*60) == 0):
            TC += 1
```